# Can you explain how the lists were iterated?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

```
list_1=[7,8,9,1,2,4]
list_2=[1,2,4]

for i in list_1:
   for j in list_2:
       if i>j:
         print(i)
```

main problem i didn't understand the output

```
7
7
7
8
8
8
9
9
9
2
4
4
```

Why there are 3 times(7,8,9) 2 times(4,4)....
What is the logic
I am a beginner..

Comment: In the first iteration of list_2, `7` is not greater than `1, 2, 4`, so it prints it 3 times, same for `8` and `9`. However, for `1`, it is not greater than `1, 2, 4` so it never gets printed. For `2`, it is greater than `1` so it prints once. For `4`, it is greater than `1, 2` so it prints twice. Isn't that clear from the nested loops?

Comment: why don't you do a `print (i, j)` before the if statement to see what value is being computed in each iteration of the for loop. It will help you understand the code better

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do nested for loops work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135519/how-do-nested-for-loops-work)

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested loop. The first loop iterates through `list_1` items `[7,8,9,1,2,4]`. The second loop iterates through `list_2` items `[1,2,4]`

For each iteration of `list_1`, you are checking if the value in `list_1` is greater than the values in `list_2`. So the code works as follows:

outer loop: `i = 7`, iterate through inner loop values

```
if 7 > 1  #this is True - so print 7

if 7 > 2  #this is True - so print 7

if 7 > 4  #this is True - so print 7
```

Outer loop: `i = 8`, iterate through inner loop values

```
if 8 > 1  #this is True - so print 8

if 8 > 2  #this is True - so print 8

if 8 > 4  #this is True - so print 8
```

Outer loop: `i = 9`, iterate through inner loop values

```
if 9 > 1  #this is True - so print 9

if 9 > 2  #this is True - so print 9

if 9 > 4  #this is True - so print 9
```

Outer loop: `i = 1`, iterate through inner loop values

```
if 1 > 1  #this is False - so nothing is printed

if 1 > 2  #this is False - so nothing is printed

if 1 > 4  #this is False - so nothing is printed
```

Outer loop: `i = 2`, iterate through inner loop values

```
if 2 > 1  #this is True  - so print 2

if 1 > 2  #this is False - so nothing is printed

if 1 > 4  #this is False - so nothing is printed
```

Outer loop: `i = 4`, iterate through inner loop values

```
if 4 > 1  #this is True  - so print 4

if 4 > 2  #this is True  - so print 4

if 1 > 4  #this is False - so nothing is printed
```

This results in what you got as output.

Answer (score 1):

### Understand the loop

1. When you execute, `for i in list_1` means i iterating through the
   entire items in `list_1` (`7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 4`).
2. As the execution
   reached `for j in list_2`, `j` iterating through `list_2` (`1, 2, 4`).
3. Now `if i > j` code means if the value `i` is greater than all `j`, than print the value in `i`.

### Workflow

---

When `i` start iterating, `j` start iterating too. And `i` won't continue to the next element until `j` finish iterating.

Say `i` is `7`, means `if 7 is greater than 1, 2, and 4` then `print 7`.

So `7` will be printed 3 times, because `7 > 1`, `7 > 2`, and `7 > 4`.

Then `i` continue to the next element, which in this case is `8` (the next index in `list_1`).

And it will be printed 3 times because `8 > 1`, `8 > 2`, `8 > 4`.

---

Now say `i` has reached number `2`. Why it only prints out once? Because `2` is only greater than `1` in this case.